# How to append Item.Id to JQuery.Modal Dialog MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I'm using the example of  [Matt Hidinger](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx)  to create modal forms with Jquery.

I tried something like

```
//Javascript click event
$("#Edit").click(function () {
        var grid = jQuery('#Tareas');
        var selId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', selId, 'TareaId');
        if(myCellData=="") {
            alert("Select Task to Edit");
        } else {
        location.href = '/Task/Edit/'+myCellData;
            }
    });

<button id="Edit" class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="editDialog" data-dialog-Title="Edit" title="editDialog" style="border: 1; background: transparent">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Detail.png")" />
</button>
```

But I can not capture the click event. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: are you clicking on the image or the button??

Comment: try addding the id to the img and calling the click by that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because not only need to send the id of the row, but also needed to show the edit based on user profile, I have decided to implement an action column.

```
$.ActionsFormatter = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
// column 10 contains true or false from de user profile action
// column 1 contains the item.id
var c = rowObject[10];
if(c) {
     var src = '@Url.Content("~/Content/")' + 'Edit_16.png';
     return "<a class='openDialog' data-dialog-id='editDialog' data-dialog-Title='Edit Task' title='editDialog' href ='@Url.Action("Edit")'"+rowObject[1]+"><img title='edit' src='" + src + "' alt='edit' title='edit' /> </a>";
     } 
     else {
           return "";
     }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `#Edit`. This means that JQuery is looking through the DOM for an object with the `ID` of **Edit**. It can't find it because you're not setting the `ID` of your `ActionLink` to "Edit".

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MyThing", new { id = item.Id }, 
    new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "editDialog", 
        data_dialog_title = "Edit", @id = "Edit" })
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that does not help me, I need to pass the id of the selected row in the grid